# How do I use loop to generate column names dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have table `sdata` and it has 35 columns (`id`, `name`, `TRx1`, `TRx2`, `TRx3`, `TRx4`,..., `TRx30`, `city`, `score`, `total`)

I want to fetch data from the `TRx1,...TRx30` columns.

Can I use loop here?

I did following code:

```
DECLARE @flag INT
DECLARE @sel varchar(255)
DECLARE @frm varchar(255)

SET @flag = 1;
SET @sel = 'select TRx';
SET @frm = ' from sdata';

exec(@sel + 

    (WHILE @flag <=5
        @flag
    SET @flag = @flag + 1)

+ @frm)
```

What wrong am I doing? And how can I resolve this?

Comment: Copy/pasting and changing the column names would be a million times faster (and less complicated/error-prone) than writing a `while` loop to construct a dynamic query..

Comment: don't use a loop in SQL.  never.  don't do it.  SQL is not about loops.

Comment: I dont understand why people hate while loop. That `loop` is just for generating string nothing wrong at all.... When you process the data record by record (ie) `RBAR` that is when you have to worry but this loop is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Prdp -- It is not that I hate loops the problem is that loops are slow.  Loops don't work well  -- they "do" work in SQL, but not well.  This means (as an example) where I work there are about 2000 queries an hour that if they were implemented as loops they would never finish and crash the entire system.  SQL is designed to not use loops -- while you can use them it but is a REALLY REALLY REALLY bad idea.  Also, there is **nothing** you can do with a loop in SQL you can't also do without a loop and faster so why use them?

Comment: Do not use this merely to save keystrokes, because it makes a big difference in SQL if your query is static or dynamic. Unless the `5` in your example above will be a variable or parameter, don't bother with this and just write out the query in full, clumsy as it may look. Also consider simply retrieving all columns and having the client filter. This may or may not be appropriate with regards to performance, but it certainly simplifies things on the SQL end.

Comment: @Hogan - Hey its just string concatenation. It is not hitting any physical table inside loop. So it should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier to do by just copy/pasting the column names and changing them to be the correct one.  *However* if you must do it this way, I do not advise using a loop at all.  This method uses a tally table to generate the columns you want to select (in this example, columns `1` through `30`, but that can be changed), then generates a dynamic SQL statement to execute against the `SData` table:

```
Declare @From   Int = 1,
        @To     Int = 30,
        @Sql    NVarchar (Max)

Declare @Columns Table (Col Varchar (255))

;With Nums As
(
    Select  *
    From    (Values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) As V(N)
), Tally As
(
    Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) As N
    From        Nums    A   --10
    Cross Join  Nums    B   --100
    Cross Join  Nums    C   --1000
)
Insert  @Columns
Select  'TRx' + Cast(N As Varchar)
From    Tally
Where   N Between @From And @To

;With Cols As
(
    Select  (
                Select  QuoteName(Col) + ',' As [text()]
                From    @Columns
                For Xml Path ('')
            ) As Cols
) 
Select  @Sql = 'Select ' + Left(Cols, Len(Cols) - 1) + ' From SData'
From    Cols

--Select    @Sql
Execute (@Sql)
```

*Note: The `--Select @Sql` section is there to preview the generated query before executing it.*

Comment: Thanks. The code runs perfect but its hard to understand as i am new in sql.

Answer (score 3):

If your table name is sdata, this code should work for you:

```
-- Grab the names of all the remaining columns
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @columns = STUFF ( ( SELECT N'], [' + name
            FROM sys.columns
           WHERE object_id = (select top 1 object_id FROM sys.objects where name = 'sdata') 
             AND name LIKE 'TRx%' -- To limit which columns
           ORDER BY column_id
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']';
PRINT @columns
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM sdata';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC (@sql);
```

Note I included PRINT statements so you could see what's going on. You might want to comment out the EXEC while testing.

Comment: Using `QUOTENAME` to escape the columns is slightly more robust (though admittedly you're a masochist if you use `]` in your column names). `SELECT QUOTENAME(name) + ','` and strip off the final `,` with `REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE((...)), 1, 1, ''))`.

Comment: This is missing `AND name LIKE 'TRx%'` if we only want those columns. (One of the strengths of this approach is the ability to pick and choose from actual columns based on any criteria we like, so you may as well show that off.)

Comment: Right... I wanted to provide a more 'generic' template that could be customized, as well as being as 'clear' as possible.  I'll update the snippet to be more clear though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the column names like this:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'my name here'
```